# Virtual Desktop Menu not showing, Alt + Tab stops working after pressing Win + Tab

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer, virtual-desktop

Using Windows 11 Pro, 10.0.22621, Build 22621, Lenovo.

I have Windows Virtual Desktops running & using Ctrl + Win + Right Arrow or Ctrl + Win + Left Arrow  I can move between different virtual desktops.
If I use Win + Tab to access the Virtual Desktop Manager

1. It doesn't show the Virtual Desktop Manager
2. Alt + Tab stops working until I restart the Windows Explorer Process.

When I restart Windows Explorer, Alt + Tab works fine, until I press Win + Tab.

Using HotkeyDetective t([GitHub](https://github.com/ITachiLab/hotkey-detective?search=1)) to search for what application is getting the command, both Alt + Tab and Win + Tab both link to C:\Windows\explorer.exe
[image]

What I've tried:

1. Update Windows.
2. update Explorer Patcher
3. update Explorer
4. changing Registry key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer, Change AltTabSettings from 0 (default ) to 1 (not pretty), & restart explorer.  This continues to work even after pressing Win + Tab

Expectations:
Win + Tab should display all Virtual Desktops, it doesn't.
Alt + Tab should continue to allow switching between programs, it doesn't working after using Win + Tab.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Ed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue appears to be caused by my use of [Explorer Patcher](https://github.com/valinet/ExplorerPatcher), specifically issue [1687](https://github.com/valinet/ExplorerPatcher/issues/1687).

According to issue [1802](https://github.com/valinet/ExplorerPatcher/issues/1802), rolling back Windows update KB5029263 resolves the issue and that worked in my case.